# Vertically align dynamic text within a fixed div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a div that has a height of 200px. I have text in there that is sometimes one line, sometimes two lines. How would I center the text in there when the text's height changes? It seems like it would be simple to do but I cannot find a solution anywhere.

Right now my html is `<div class="class1"><?php echo $variable; ?></div>`

and my css is

```
.class1 {
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
left:235px; //Unimportant to question
height:200px;
width:415px;
top:15px;
text-align:center;
font-size:36px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Although this doesn't center it. I have tryed using `line-height:200px;`, although then when my text becomes two lines the next line is 200 pixels under the first one.

Comment: Can you provide code samples? It's hard to determine what a solution is without any context.

Comment: @badAdviceGuy I have added samples. I apologize for not posting it with the sample.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a dummy element (or use `:before`) and set its height to 100%. Then, using inline blocks and `vertical-align`, you can vertically center:

```
.vertical-center:before, .vertical-center > * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.vertical-center:before {
    height: 100%;
    content:'';
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VRXE7/1/)

Comment: This vertically aligned the first line, but in instances where the text is two lines the second line was 200px (I'm assuming 200px) below the first line.

Comment: @user2087587 You must place the contents inside an inline-block wrapper.

Comment: I changed my html to <div class="class1"><span class="class2">*text*</div></span> and added .class2 {display:inline-block;} to my code and now when the text is one line, it is perfectly vertically aligned. Yet when it's two lines, now both lines are moved down 200px from the top of the div. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @user2087587 Then use `<div class="class1"><span><?php echo $variable; ?></span></div>`, and use my code above replacing `.vertical-center` with `.class1`.

Comment: I had already replaced .vertical-center with .class1, I had assumed that was what you had meant.

Comment: @user2087587 Yes, but also note that you need a wrapping `<span>`

Comment: Right, that is what I did when I put the contents inside the inline-block wrapper. my code is now `<div class="class1"><span class="class2"><?php echo $variable; ?> </span> </div>`

Answer (score 1):

By using `vertical-align:middle;` and `display:table-cell;` you can vertically the multi-line text.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5pupq/)**

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Adding display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; had no effect on my text :/

Comment: Is the position:absolute necessary on the div?

Comment: Yes, it is possible that my position:absolute; is throwing it off?

Comment: Unfortunately in order to move it relative to an image that is to the left, I can't find any other way to position it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

to your div.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VRXE7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `valign` HTML attribute or [vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) CSS property:

```
.your-div
{
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;

    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it is simple. Use following:

```
<div style="vertical-align: middle; ">
   <p>some text</p>
</div>
```